# Fork() vs number of cores

Tags: c, fork, cpu

I am looking to do some data processing of some 6700 files and am using fork() to handle different sets of calculations on the data. Will getting a CPU with a higher core count allow me to run more forks()? Currently I am using a quad core with 8 threads, forking() 8 times, takes me about an hour per file. If I had a 64 core processor and forked() 64 times (splitting up calculations), would that decrease the time by about 8???

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Depends on the bottleneck. If you're I/O bound more cores won't help at all, it might make it worse; you need faster I/O or a better algorithm. Same for being memory bound. If you're CPU bound then increasing the cores, as long as they're as fast, should improve performance, but only by brute force. If you're seeing a theme here, it's to try to improve your algorithm before throwing more cores at it. Perhaps also rethinking your data format.

Comment: @Schwern So basically I am processing stock data. I read all historical prices into a struct, then store 1-50 moving averages for each day in struct, this does not take a long time O(n). Then I simulate historical data to find the best MA to use to calculate when to buy and sell, this takes the longest (assuming O(n!). I do realize that this is factorial time (nested for loops), I have been trying to find a better way to do this, but can't think of any

Comment: @JamieDocka Ask a question about the O(n!) part. It might be faster to dump the data into a database, index it, and let the database do it.

Comment: OP Why didn't you include that information into your question? You are asking a XY question - asking about "forks to some handle sets of calculations" instead of concentrating exactly on your algorithm that is used in reading historical data. For that - please create a new question, please post your algorithm, please post sample input files, please post sample output, please create an [MCVE] - you'll get help a lot faster. Remember about rules of optimization - do not optimize. Then do not optimize. Then _profile_ the code.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically no, according to [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Probably also practically, because many resources are shared (the caches, the operating system calls, the disk, etc.), but this really depends on your algorithm. For example, if your algorithm is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) and is cpu-bound, than you may notice a great improvement increasing the cores to 64.

A note after reading the comments of the question: if you have a complexity of O(n!), it is possible that your algorithm is simply impossible to be executed in a realistic time. For example, if your input is n=42, and let's say that you machine is able to do 1 billion of operation per seconds, then the time required to execute your algorithm is greater than the age of the universe.